# Rails, postgres and console give different row count for the same model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

Please bear with me this is a very strange problem. I have been trying to address it for the past 6 hours.

This is hosted on Heroku.

Ruby (2.1.7)

I have a rails (4.1.1) model Order

1. Connecting to the DB (Postgres 9.4) via Postico

   ```
   Select count(*) from orders 

   result 897 rows
   ```
2. Heroku Rails console

   ```
   Order.count

   Result 906
   ```
3. Orders View Calling in the index controller

   ```
   Order.all.order(created: :desc)

   Result 897 rows
   ```
4. Calling from a library file passing to another page

   ```
   Order.count 

   Result 906
   ```

I thought the procedure making the inserts wasn't working but I have throughly worked through them and they are clean, then I started looking the db still no joy. The the console and the another view produce a different result than the above. When viewed the data in the Console is what I expected, ie the missing inserts from the methods. The fact that it happens different with two different sets of call, leaves baffled, I don't know where to isoloate this issue.

It's a strange problem

Comment: very strange, especially since `Order.count` actually runs `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"`. Try running `heroku run rails db` and see what you get there.

Comment: is there any default_scope in your Order model?

Comment: default scope would reduce the value of `Order.count` @fengd

Comment: You have just one DB, correct? i.e. no DB_test, DB_development, DB_production.

Comment: Thanks all. I removed all the default scopes in Order there was only one, in any case it was just a order by.

Comment: Thanks all. I removed all the default scopes in Order there was only one, in any case it was just a order by. I thought it might the relationship between OrderItems and Order but the data is clean in the console

Comment: Toby 1 Kenobi, I rand 'code' heroku run rails db and got 897. What do you think that means?